# Are NIST approved Format Preserving Encryption algorithms public domain or patented?

Tags: encryption

NIST has approved two FPE algorithms FF1 and FF3, however, Voltage claims a patent on FF1 and potentially FF3.  The [Letter of Assurance](https://csrc.nist.gov/csrc/media/projects/block-cipher-techniques/documents/bcm/proposed-modes/ffx/ffx-voltage-ip.pdf) issued by Voltage in 2013 states in general terms:

```
Voltage agrees that upon request it will make
available a non-exclusive license, under reasonable rates with or without compensation, to an unrestricted number of applicants on a worldwide basis with reasonable terms and conditions
```

I'm looking to clarify if which, if any, of these two FPE algorithms can be implemented without requiring a license.

Capital One has provided an open source [Go implementation of FF1 and FF3](https://github.com/capitalone/fpe).  A [Java implementation of FF1 and FF3](https://sourceforge.net/projects/format-preserving-encryption/) is also available but it has not been updated for FF3-1.  Both provide a Apache v2 license. A C open source [implementation](https://github.com/0NG/Format-Preserving-Encryption) is available with a MIT license for FF1 and FF3 (but not updated for FF3-1).

Comment: You should probably hire a lawyer that specializes in patent law.

Comment: It's not reasonable to expect developers wishing to use free, open source software to hire a patent lawyer. Especially when the algorithms in question are part of a national standard by NIST.

Comment: That is very fair. It does not, however, change the nature of international IP law, which is complex, non-obvious, and not derivable just from "reading the specs" (i.e. the text of laws and treaties). Legal questions, unfortunately, are only answerable by those who know the current and relevant law in your jurisdiction and any other jurisdiction that you care about. Best of luck. I happen to know members of the Capital One (mobile) development team and if their Go devs are anything similar, they're excellent and very helpful people. You may want to reach out to them about their implementation.

Comment: That said, if you want a non-authoritative answer from someone with no legal expertise, looking solely at the information you've presented, it sounds like Voltage claims a patent, and you would need to discuss licensing terms with them if you want to be certain that they don't bother you in the future (or do whatever you want, and maybe they'll bother you and maybe they won't). Whether that's fair or a good system of IP law isn't really something StackOverflow can help you with.

Comment: I've confirmed that Microfocus owns a patent on the FF1 algorithm and requires a license for its use.  The license cost is revenue based, in the range of 2%.  The license does not permit the use of FF1 in open source code, and using such open source code would require a license.

Comment: I think its a very good question. Finding it relevant and helpful with what i am doing. Thanks for bringing it up